# Multilevel model for change- time-varying variables at different waves to outcome

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, time-varying-covariate

I am using UKHLS youth survey where an outcome for *wellbeing* occurs at waves 2,4,6 and 8.

I have predictors such as computer screen usage and many others I would like to use occurring at waves 1,3,5,7. I would like to use computer screen usage as a time-varying variables. There are also other predictors that I would like to keep static from these waves at say at 1.

My question is- does the multilevel model allow you to use time-varying or fixed variables that occur at 1,3,5,7 when the outcome of interest occurs at 2,4,6,8?

I ask because there are 100s of potentially useful variables at odd waves which I would like to potentially use. Is there a specific way to encorporate them into the model?

Comment: Are there any predictors you want to use at waves 2, 4, 6, or 8 or are *all* of the predictors of interest measured on the odd-numbered waves?

Comment: Hi sorry for the very delayed reply. I will write what I was told here and this answer may help individuals reading it. The predictor variables all occurred at odd waves. This sets up a 'lagged' situation which actually is a common practice. It is argued that this improves the 'causal chain'. It is mentioned in Singer and Willett (2003)- chapter  5 which may help. Page 180 which gives more surrounding details etc. Subject to careful coding and so on